# The higher partial derivatives of the coefficients of the first fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In a surface $S$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$,we consider the exponential map center at point $p\in S$,and get a geodesic polar coordinate expression $\vec{r}=\vec{r}(\rho,\theta)$ of $S$,then we construct a transformation of coordinates $x=\rho \cos\theta$,$y=\rho\sin\theta$,and denote that $E=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \rho}\cdot\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \rho}$, $F=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \rho}\cdot\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \theta}$, $G=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \theta}\cdot\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \theta}$, $g_{11}=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial x}$, $g_{12}=g_{21}=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial y}$, $g_{22}=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial y}$.We know that $E=1$ and $F=0$. My question is: Can we use $\frac{\partial^3\sqrt G}{\partial\rho^3}$to express $\frac{\partial^2 g_{11}}{\partial x^2}$ ,$\frac{\partial^2 g_{11}}{\partial y^2}$, $\frac{\partial^2 g_{12}}{\partial x^2}$, $\frac{\partial^2 g_{12}}{\partial y^2}$ ,$\frac{\partial^2 g_{22}}{\partial x^2}$,$\frac{\partial^2 g_{22}}{\partial y^2}$? Or find some relations between $\frac{\partial^3\sqrt G}{\partial\rho^3}$ and them? I already know that $\lim\limits_{\rho\rightarrow 0}\sqrt G=0$, $\lim\limits_{\rho\rightarrow 0}(\sqrt G)_\rho=1$, $(\sqrt G)_{\rho\rho}=-K\sqrt G$, $\lim\limits_{\rho\rightarrow 0}(\sqrt G)_{\rho \rho \rho}=K(p)$,and that$$
\left(
\begin{array}{l}
g_{11}& g_{12}\\
g_{21}& g_{22}
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{l}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}& \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\\
\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}& \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{l}
1&0\\
0&G
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{l}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}& \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\
\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}& \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}
\end{array}
\right)
$$.